# Compare 2 strings in ASP Classic to find new and removed elements

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Okay, I am on deep water with this, and I do not know where to start .. In ASP Classic I have a string from a form that I need to Compare with a string from DB .. The string from the form are the new values that should be loaded into the DB, but before that I need to know which elements are already in the DB, which are new and which will be removed .. let me explain the "concept":

I have these 2 string values:

- **From Form (New values) :** APR, BJE, BNI, KLR, LMO03, LMO05
- **From Database (Existing) :** APR, BJE, BNI, BIA, BOK, CHO

So in the above case I would need 2 new variables

Variable #1 :
This should contain new entries from form that is not already in DB, in the case above this would contain the following.

- KLR, LMO03, LMO05

Variable #2 :
This should contain entries from DB that are not in the form, and there for will be deleted, in the case above this would contain the following.

- BIA, BOK, CHO

What I have is :

The Requst.Form above explained and the following select :

```
DIM SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn, SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersSQL, objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers, PriviouslyGroupMembers

PriviouslyGroupMembers = ""

Set SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn.ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB; DATA SOURCE=<SERVER>;UID=<USERNAME>;PWD=<PASSWORD>;DATABASE=<DATABASE>"
SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn.Open

SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersSQL = "SELECT *  FROM EFP_SITE_PRIVILEGE_MEMBERS WHERE PrivilegeLevelID = " & trim(Request.Form("PrivilegeLevel")) & ";"

Set objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers = SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn.Execute(SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersSQL)

While Not objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers.EOF

        PriviouslyGroupMembers = PriviouslyGroupMembers + objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers("PrivilegeUserID") + ", "

        objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers.MoveNext

Wend
objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers.Close
Set objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers = Nothing

PriviouslyGroupMembers = left(PriviouslyGroupMembers,len(PriviouslyGroupMembers)-1)
```

How can I crack this?

**What I have so far :**

I have managed to get first variable now, the NewGroupMembers but my effort to get variable GroupMembersRemoved I have dificulties seeing how I can do and need some help.

```
    DIM SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn, SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersSQL, objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers, NewGroupMembers, GroupMembersRemoved

    NewGroupMembers = ""
    GroupMembersRemoved = ""

    Set SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn.ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB; DATA SOURCE=<SERVER>;UID=<USERNAME>;PWD=<PASSWORD>;DATABASE=<DATABASE>"
    SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn.Open

    
    ' Getting NewGroupMembers

        Dim values, i
        values = Split(Request.Form("EFPAdminUsers"), ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(values)

            SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) as isUserIn  FROM EFP_SITE_PRIVILEGE_MEMBERS WHERE PrivilegeLevelID = " & trim(Request.Form("PrivilegeLevel")) & " AND PrivilegeUserID = '" & trim(values(i)) & "';"
            
            Set objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers = SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn.Execute(SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersSQL)           


            While Not objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers.EOF


                IF objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers("isUserIn") <= "0" THEN

                    NewGroupMembers = NewGroupMembers + trim(values(i)) + ","

                END IF

            objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers.MoveNext

            Wend                

        Next    


    ' Getting GroupMembersRemoved

        

            SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersSQL = "SELECT PrivilegeUserID as isUserIn  FROM EFP_SITE_PRIVILEGE_MEMBERS WHERE PrivilegeLevelID = " & trim(Request.Form("PrivilegeLevel")) & ";"
            
            Set objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers = SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersConn.Execute(SelectExistingPrivilegeMembersSQL)           

            While Not objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers.EOF

                values = Split(Request.Form("EFPAdminUsers"), ",")
                For i = 0 To UBound(values)


                    IF objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers("PrivilegeUserID") <> trim(values(i)) THEN

                        GroupMembersRemoved = GroupMembersRemoved + objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers("PrivilegeUserID") + ","

                    END IF

                Next

            objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers.MoveNext

            Wend                



    objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers.Close
    Set objSelectExistingPrivilegeMembers = Nothing
```

Comment: Why are you concatenating the results of the SQL?   You probably want to go the other way around and split the string from the form.  Then set up another array of the same size indicating if for each if it is to be added, deleted or left as is.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf  .. You where right in that I should not concatinate it, I have therefor managed to get the data for variable NewGroupMembers and have tried to turn it around and get GroupMembersRemoved, but I cant seem to get it working, ..  I have pastede my new code under  "**What I have so far**" in post .. how can I do this/whats wrong with my logic? :-)

Comment: For the removed, you will have to set a flag for each While loop,  e.g. Remove=True, and loop through For loop, and if it is found set the flag to False.   After the for loop, check the remove flag, if it is True, only then add it to the GroupMembersRemoved

Comment: @Dijkgraaf that makes sense .. do you have some example you could link to for that? .. I will offcause try to google it also

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Would it be foolish to inject the form data to a temp db, and make a SQL compare of the 2 tables instead? .. I am not able to find any example.

Comment: You could loop through each array while doing a replace in the other array to produce arrays of what is left from each comparison.